# Send Mail with Outlook on Exchange Account

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to send EMails with C# and the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` library.

I am locked in, on my Outlook account with `a@domain.com` and got the rights on the exchange server to send mails from `b@domain.com` and `c@domain.com`.

I don't find any way to send a mail with `B` or `C`.

I got everything working for my user account which has the mail `a@domain.com`.

Now I can't find a way to get the account of `b@domain.com` and send a mail in the name of `B`.

My Question:

How do I get access to the other accounts?

That's the code I have:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
        public static Outlook.Account GetAccountForEmailAddress(Outlook.Application application, string smtpAddress)
    {

        // Loop over the Accounts collection of the current Outlook session. 
        Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts;
        if (_IsDebug)
            Console.WriteLine($"Anzahl Accounts: {accounts.Count}");
        foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
        {
            // When the e-mail address matches, return the account. 
            if (_IsDebug)
                Console.WriteLine($"Account: {account.SmtpAddress}");
            if (String.Compare(account.SmtpAddress, smtpAddress, true) == 0)
            {
                return account;
            }
        }
        throw new System.Exception(string.Format("No Account with SmtpAddress: {0} exists!", smtpAddress));
    }
        static void SendEMail(string emailadress)
    {
        try
        {
            var outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
            var outlookMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApplication.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            outlookMailItem.SendUsingAccount = GetAccountForEmailAddress(outlookApplication, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SENDER]);


            if (_IsDebug)
                Console.WriteLine($"Absender: {outlookMailItem?.SendUsingAccount?.SmtpAddress}");

            outlookMailItem.HTMLBody = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[BODY];

            if (_IsDebug)
                Console.WriteLine($"Body: {outlookMailItem?.HTMLBody}");

            var file = GetPDFFile();
            if (_IsDebug)
                Console.WriteLine($"File: {file?.Name}");

            if (file == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Keine Datei gefunden!");
                return;
            }

            string attachementDisplayName = file.Name;

            int attachementPosition = outlookMailItem.HTMLBody.Length + 1;
            int attachementType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;

            if (_IsDebug)
                Console.WriteLine($"Dateianhang: {file.FullName}");

            Outlook.Attachment outlookAttachement = outlookMailItem.Attachments.Add(file.FullName, attachementType, attachementPosition, attachementDisplayName);

            outlookMailItem.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SUBJECT];

            Outlook.Recipients outlookRecipients = outlookMailItem.Recipients;
            Outlook.Recipient outlookRecipient = outlookRecipients.Add(emailadress);

            outlookRecipient.Resolve();

            outlookMailItem.Send();

            outlookRecipient = null;
            outlookRecipients = null;
            outlookMailItem = null;
            outlookApplication = null;

            if (_IsDebug)
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to grant the owner of the sending mailbox Send As permissions on the mailboxes you want to send the emails from.  Send on behalf of permissions will work but will say "A on behalf of B" as the sender.

Comment: You can use PowerShell: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff852815(v=exchsrvcs.149).aspx